# I have an error Expected `onTimeUpdate` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `number` type. in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm novice i React but i have problem with initProgressBar function.
My func

```
const initProgressBar = (num) => {
        var player = document.getElementById(`player-${num.index}`);
        var length = player.duration;
        var current_time = player.currentTime;
    
        // calculate total length of value
        var totalLength = calculateTotalValue(length);
        $(`.end-time-${num.index}`).html(totalLength);
    
        // calculate current value time
        $(`.start-time-${num.index}`).html(currentTime);
    
        var progressbar = document.getElementById(`seekObj-${num.index}`);
        progressbar.value = player.currentTime / player.duration;
        progressbar.addEventListener("click", seek);
    
        var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
        if (player.currentTime === player.duration) {
            $(`#play-btn-${num.index}`).removeClass("pause");
            $(`#play-btn-${num.index}`).addClass("button");
        }
    }
```

My return.

```
<audio id={`player-${index}`} onTimeUpdate={setTimeout(initProgressBar, 500, {index})} src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000${trackUrl}`}></audio>
```

I have an error `Expected onTimeUpdate listener to be a function, instead got a value of number type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
<audio id={`player-${index}`} onTimeUpdate={() => setTimeout(initProgressBar, 500, {index})} src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000${trackUrl}`}></audio>
```

You want to provide onTimeUpdate a function to run. The way you wrote it, you are calling the setTimeout function and providing whatever it returns to onTimeUpdate. I've simply changed your code to give it a function that says (whenever you call this, we run setTimeout)